# footer showing different heights in different devices in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I am using this piece of code to have a footer at the very bottom in react native .However on different devices , the height appears to have changed .I want all devices to have same height from the bottom .
Here is the footer code .

```
 footer:{
    position: 'absolute',
   left: 0, 
   top: windowHeight  - 135, 
   width: windowWidth,
   height: 180,
   backgroundColor: "#436ab2",
   opacity:0.5
   },
```

I see that use of top variable is doing something .How can we assure that things are constant for all devices .

Comment: Height must have a unit like 'px' or use 180/16 = `11.25rem`. BTW: top: -135 too (plain CSS, dunno about react).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
footer: {
   position: 'absolute', 
   bottom: 0, 
   width: '100%',
   height: 180,
   backgroundColor: "#436ab2",
   opacity: 0.5
}
```